# Building a form and printing in a block

Tags: forms

I would like to build a form, and print it in a block via `hook_block()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887321/passing-arguments-using-drupal-get-form

Comment: Does it have to be hook_block() ?

Answer (score 0):

That is what done from [user_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_block/6), which contains the following code.

```
  case 0:
    // For usability's sake, avoid showing two login forms on one page.
    if (!$user->uid && !(arg(0) == 'user' && !is_numeric(arg(1)))) {

      $block['subject'] = t('User login');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
    }
    return $block;
```